# Quadratic Taylor Polynomial in Multiple Variables

Tags: taylor-expansion

I know of two different formulas for the determination of the Quadratic Taylor Polynomial:

- One with the [Multi Index Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation): 
   $$f(x_0 + \zeta) = \sum_{\vert\alpha\vert \le 2} \frac{1}{\alpha!} \, \partial^{\alpha} \, f(x_0) \, \zeta^{\alpha}$$
- One without:
   $$ f(x_0 + \zeta) = f(x_0) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \partial_{i} \, f(x_0) \, \zeta_i + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,\,j=1}^{n} \partial_{i} \, \partial_{j} \, f(x_0) \, \zeta_i \, \zeta_j$$

Let's pretend $f = f(x,y)$.

I'm curious about how often the term containing $\partial_{x} \partial_{y}$ appears. With the Multiple Index Notation this would be the tuple (1, 1), therefore the term appears exactly once $\frac{1}{2} \partial_{x} \partial_{y}  \,f(x_0) \zeta_x \, \zeta_y$. Sadly the second sum in the later formula contains both of the cases ($i = 1, j = 2$ and $i = 2, j = 1$), which results in two terms $\frac{1}{2} \partial_{x} \partial_{y} \, f(x_0) \zeta_x \, \zeta_y$.

Which is the right calculation of the Quadratic Taylor Polynomial? And what am I doing wrong/missing in my "*wrong*" formula?

Comment: In multi index rotation $\alpha!=1$ when $\alpha =(1,1)$

Comment: @N74 Thank you! Seem's like I missed this one.. If you'd like to post this comment in form of a short answer I would be happy to accept it!

Comment: I thought it was too short for an answer... but it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In multi index notation $\alpha !=1$ when $\alpha=(1,1)$

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what to tell you; the cleanest way to remember it is, with column vector $\zeta,$
$$ f( x_0 + \zeta) \approx f(x_0) + \nabla f(x_0) \cdot \zeta + \frac{1}{2} \zeta^T H \zeta,  $$
where $H$ is the symmetric Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives, evaluated at $x_0.$ Oh, $\nabla f$ is the gradient vector of $f.$

I cannot tell whether this is part of your difficulty, but mixed partials commute once the function is smooth enough. That is a quick application of Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: When you evaluate your formula, does it contain the term $\frac{1}{2} \partial_x \partial_y \, f(x_0) \zeta_x \zeta_y$ or $\partial_x \partial_y \, f(x_0) \zeta_x \zeta_y$?

Comment: @Herickson I think you should work it out yourself for the example $f(x,y) = 5 x^2 + 4xy + 7 y^2, $ at the origin, although the Hessian is constant.